# Could the REQUEST_METHOD Server Variable Ever Be Null or Empty in IIS?

Tags: iis, iis-7, server, iis-7.5, iis-8

Could the REQUEST_METHOD server variable ever be Null or empty (or anything else besides GET and POST) for any request?

I am asking in the context of an IIS 7 (or newer) environment.